# Password in the terminal

Tags: password, gnome-terminal

I am new to Ubuntu (trying to get away from the clutches of Microsoft).

I downloaded Ubuntu 14, then upgraded to Ubuntu 16.
Now I am trying to understand the command line, and every time I try to do something such as `apt-get install qbittorrent` ,  I am asked to give my password. My question is: What password? is this the one I gave when installed Ubuntu for first time?. I did try to use it but it does not take it.
Is very frustrating being stone walled, so any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Yes it is the password you set when you were doing the install.  Just FYI, that command to install would need to be sudo apt-get install qbittorrent  otherwise it will not work, but for sure the sudo password should be the one you set when you were installing Ubuntu.

Comment: Note that the characters you type will not show — not even `****`/`····`, just keep typing.

Answer (score 5):

This is in fact the same password you use when you login your user.

Make sure you not have Caps-Lock activated and so on. Unless you messed something up greatly this should work. You should be even able to switch to the super-user by using `sudo su`, `sudo -i` and such commands, which is not recommended because in this case you forfeit the security layer which keeps you from messing up things.

Comment: I apologize for not answering sooner.

Comment: Your welcome, if my answer helped you and solved your problem you can accept it by clicking the check-mark beside it to accept it.